# How to get contact list from Exchange Server in Android?

Tags: android, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office365

How to obtain the contacts from  **`global address list(GAL)`** of 
 **`Microsoft Office 365`** .

or How do I retrieve **`global contacts`** with **`Exchange Web Services (EWS)`**?

Please Help....

Answer (score 2):

Android Application that looks up **`Exchange GAL`** for **`contacts`**

[**corporateaddressbook**](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/)

Also u can refer

**[Searching the Global Address List by Using the Search Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631384%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)**

**[ResolveNames Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563518%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)**